# How to assign a data column value to specific word using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a field in my table in which I would like to set a string  like “COMPLETE”.   Initially the field is empty  and I want to set it some kind of text like “COMPLETE”  Here is what I have so far…

```
   string ID = GV_Action.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Update", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID;

    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

in my Strored procedure below i am using a default ID but would like to pass the paramter ID  and not use the fixed value how can i do that?
here is how i created the proc
CREATE PROC sp_Update

AS

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'UpdateField';

GO

EXEC sp_Update

and here is job that i am calling when the procedure kicks off
update MyTable

set Status = 'Complete'
  where Post_ID = 303

Comment: there is no table anywhere here. do you mean database table or html table?

Comment: You should write a stored procedure, it sounds like you are trying to execute multiple statements.

Comment: sorry, i mean a database table.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fill it directly from database by

```
SELECT Count(*), 'COMPLETE' AS MyColumn FROM MyTable
```

Comment: UNeverNo, how do i tell which field to update?  do i need to say like:  set Status = 'COMPLETE'?

Comment: I guess you need to describe a little more in detail what you try to achieve. I thought it's about selecting some data plus a constant value into a datatable.

Comment: okay, i have updated the code please look above in my original post.  i am using now stored procedure but only need help passing the parameter in my stored proc.  thanks